# vstest pass pass parameter to "dotnet test" execution

Tags: vstest, vstest.console.exe

### Description

I want to run a .net core NUnit test with the vstest.console.
This is working fine but I want to pass to the "dotnet test" execution a parameter, in my case "--no-build"
How I can parse this parameter to the dotnet execution? I have not found the right runsettings variable

### Steps to reproduce

vstest.console.exe " "project.json"  /UseVsixExtensions:true /Settings:settings.runsettings

### Expected behavior

["C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test "project.json" --port 55307 --no-build]

### Actual behavior

["C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test "project.json" --port 55307 ]

### Environment

windows 7

project.json

> {
>      "version": "1.0.0-*",
>
> "dependencies": {
>    "NUnit": "3.5.0",
>   "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-3"
>   },
>
> "testRunner": "nunit",
>    "frameworks": {
>       "netcoreapp1.0": {
>          "imports": "portable-net45+win8",
>         "dependencies": {
>          "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
>           "version": "1.0.0-*",
>          "type": "platform"
>        }
>       }
>   }
>   }
>   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer from the vstudio develoment team

https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/383